# Ajax tab container still not showing on my browser

Tags: asp.net, ajax

Even though is my first usage of Ajax tab content, i spend a lot of hours tying different solutions to similar problem posted on stack over flow site.
I have check different answer from Changing  to `<ajax:ToolkitScriptManager runat="server"></ajax:ToolkitScriptManager>` Which is the answer many provided to similar question here on stack over flow. It did not work for me. Did any want know why?
here is my code:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Styles/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="main.aspx.cs" Inherits="healthcare.Treatment.main" %>

<%@ Register Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajax" %>
```

```
<div>


    <ajax:ToolkitScriptManager runat="server"></ajax:ToolkitScriptManager>

    <ajaxToolkit:TabContainer runat="server" OnDemand="True">
        <ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>
            <HeaderTemplate>Patient new treatment</HeaderTemplate>
            <ContentTemplate>
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>New Treatment</legend>

                </fieldset>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>
        <ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                Patient Previous Record 
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ContentTemplate>
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>History</legend>

                </fieldset>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>

    </ajaxToolkit:TabContainer>


</div>
```

Comment: first note is that since you used TagPrefix="ajax", then you create TapPanel and other ajax controls using <ajax:TabContainer> not <ajaxToolKit:TabContainer>

Comment: When you run into errors, it's good to tell us what those are. But before you do, check obvious things like runat="server" and making sure you're using the correct tag prefix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TabPanel should have `runAt="Server"` property.

Also make sure to use the correct TagPrefix for your ajax controls, use the same name as you defined it in the registering the assemply.

Please modify your markup to this:

```
 <ajax:ToolkitScriptManager runat="server"></ajax:ToolkitScriptManager>
    <ajax:TabContainer runat="server" OnDemand="True">
        <ajax:TabPanel runat="server">
            <HeaderTemplate>Patient new treatment</HeaderTemplate>
            <ContentTemplate>
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>New Treatment</legend>
                </fieldset>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </ajax:TabPanel>
        <ajax:TabPanel runat="server" >
            <HeaderTemplate>
                Patient Previous Record 
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ContentTemplate>
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>History</legend>
                </fieldset>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </ajax:TabPanel>
    </ajax:TabContainer>
```

Hope this helps.